# Android sql cursors slow

Tags: android, sqlite

I have this code in an activity to collect data from a database. It takes 5 seconds till the activity opens. Without this, the activity needs 2 seconds to open. It there a way to optimize this code?

All the arrays (including the one in the loop: arr_calllog_name0) has 61 items on my phone. In the emulator it is fast, with 6 items.

```
for (int i=0; i<arr_calllog_name0.size(); i++)
    {


        Cursor crname = info.getAllTitles_Stats2A(arr_calllog_name0.get(i), "1", d1, d2);
        crname.moveToFirst();
        count_in = crname.getInt(0);
        arr_calllog_numberin0.add(String.valueOf(count_in));



        Cursor crname2 = info.getAllTitles_Stats2A(arr_calllog_name0.get(i), "2", d1, d2);
        crname2.moveToFirst();
        count_out = crname2.getInt(0);
        arr_calllog_numberout0.add(String.valueOf(count_out));



        Cursor crname3 = info.sumAllTitles_StatsA(arr_calllog_name0.get(i), "1", d1, d2);
        crname3.moveToFirst();
        sum_in = crname3.getInt(0);
        arr_calllog_durationin0.add(String.valueOf(sum_in));



        Cursor crname4 = info.sumAllTitles_StatsA(arr_calllog_name0.get(i), "2", d1, d2);
        crname4.moveToFirst();
        sum_out = crname4.getInt(0);
        arr_calllog_durationout0.add(String.valueOf(sum_out));

    }
```

info is declared as `HotOrNot info = new HotOrNot(ChartsDuration.this);` where HotOrNot is the class containing the DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper class.

One query is (the other one is almost the same)

```
public Cursor getAllTitles_Stats2A(String name, String type, String date1, String date2) {
        return ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE " + KEY_DATE + " BETWEEN '" + date1 + "'" + " AND '" + date2 + "'" + " AND " + KEY_NAME + " = '" + name + "'" + " AND " + KEY_TYPE + " = '" + type + "'" + " COLLATE NOCASE", null);
    }
```

The DATABASE_TABLE has 500 items on my phone.

Comment: If you are doing four queries per "item" (whatever an "item" is), and there are 61 "items", that is likely going to be slow. However, since we have no idea what `info` is, what all those queries are, what you are querying against, what `arr_calllog_name0` is, why you think you need to run all of those queries, and so forth, it is impossible for anyone to really help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never ever use cursors in this way.  Cursors are precious (effictivly a cursor is a table of data rather than a pointer), as such, they are expensive to create in terms of CPU time. There are 2 very serious issues with your example.

1. Do not run queries in a for-loop
2. Always close a cursor when you have finished with it

You are more likely to succed if you can find a way to do this using a JOIN but without more information it is difficult to give a more definitive solution to your problem.

Comment: Queries in a for-loop is bad practice, I agree. I managed to do it without a for loop but it did not help. Why should I close the cursors? When I don't close a database, I get an error. But in case of a cursor.

Comment: Cursors use resources (i.e gobble up memory).  Failing to close them will cause resource issues.  Please note if you are using a managed cursor, then the activity should close this for you.  I find it better to manage them myself.  As for database errors, this is a common malpractice of opening and closing databases on every activity.  It's not fatal but if you really want to avoid it you need to implement a singleton model for accessing your database by overring the default application class.  You need to research this.